# Change values from nominal to numeric

Tags: data-mining, dataset, dimensionality-reduction, weka

I want to change the values of the class labels from nominal into numeric.
e.g if the values of a class are {iris-setosa,iris-virginica,iris-versicolor} i want to make them {0,1,2} so the instances will have as a value at the class label the form (0,0,1,2,0,1,1,2,0).
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It's called **Label Encoding**

In python with the help of scikit-learn you can do following:

> le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder() le.fit(["paris", "paris", "tokyo",
>   "amsterdam"])
>
> list(le.classes_)
>
> le.transform(["tokyo", "tokyo", "paris"])
>
> list(le.inverse_transform([2, 2, 1]))

Documentation for more info: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

PS: Label Encoding might be responsible for unintentional ordering of possible values. I.E. model might think that nominal value with associated numerical value 2 is more important than the nominal value with associated numerical value 1. The solution is **One Hot Encoding**.